# Why is the "bg-closer" div above the "content" div?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I copied a simple CSS menu. I want to add a background div below the menu div. Clicking this background div should close the menu. (Kind of suggested behavior on Android, I believe.)

The background div ("bg-closer") is not placed in the stacking order as I expected. It is over the menu ("contents"), but I wanted it to be below. And you do not see it (it should be red).

What is wrong? There is a CodePen here: https://codepen.io/lborgman/pen/bYpOej

```css
  .tabs {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  margin: 50px;
}

.tab {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.tab label {
  background: linear-gradient(#eee, #ccc);
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.tab label i {
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #aaa;
}

.tab [type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.content a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 5px;
}

[type=radio]:checked~label {
  z-index: 2;
}

[type=radio]:checked~label~.content {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.close-tab {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.close-tab label {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
}

[type=radio]:checked~label~.close-tab {
  z-index: 3;
}

.bg-closer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1">
  <label for="tab-1">List 1 <i>▼</i></label>
  <div class="tab close-tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-close" name="tab-group-1">
    <label for="tab-close">List 1 <i>▲</i><div class="bg-closer"></div></label>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item #1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item #2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Really Long Menu Item #3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item #4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item #5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Forget about the color. I thought I wrote "background", but I wrote "color". :-(

Comment: Could the person down-voting this please explain him/herself? (Or is it perhaps just spam?)

Comment: I see another spammer. It is a problem similar to "fake news". 
A much more intelligent system is needed to handle the spammers. https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Comment: Downvotes are not spam @Leo, they're indicators that your question is low quality, off-topic, and/or shows no research effort.

Comment: @TylerH Please read more about this subject on the internet.

Comment: Please read more about this subject on this site, which is the only place where downvotes on this site are relevant.

Comment: Specifically https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react

Comment: @TylerH Thanks, but I have already commented on that.

Comment: So now there is 3 spammers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
    z-index: 3;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Explanation:

The preceding element has `z-index:3`

```
[type=radio]:checked~label~.close-tab {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

So you need to give the next element a `z-index` with value greater than or equal to 3  to make it appear in front.

Comment: I edited the answer. I just learned Web Programming month ago so correct me if I got the explanation wrong :) ty

Comment: Please take a look at your explanation again.

Comment: What do you mean take a look at my explanation again? Yeah don't mind the downvotes, it appears that even here in SO there are trolls lol.

Comment: I think that bg-close gets a z-index of 2. Hm, maybe i am wrong?

Comment: After you click the button, it gets z-index 3 from `<div class="tab close-tab">`. You can see it by inspecting the page.

Comment: Hm, that was useful for me. I do all my development (when I have time for that) in Chrome today, but there is no easy way to get the "used value" there. But in Firefox there is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: Though this returns null on CodePen in Firefox console (but not in Chrome): 'bgc = document.querySelector(".bg-closer")'

Comment: And getComputedValue just returns "auto" in both Chrome and Firefox. :-( How do you see the "used value"?

Comment: Its `z-index` value is actually `auto`, `auto` means that the stack order is equal to its parents. Before click, it is getting `z-index:2` from its parent `label`. But after clicking the parent (`label`) is somehow also getting `z-index: auto`, meaning it is getting `z-index:3` from its grandparent. Hope we're clear :)

Comment: Yes, but it is not so easy to define parent here. (It might not be what you think.)